# How to display dynamic tabs and data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, dynamic, tabs

I have want to have dynamic tabs.I have 2 tables one is Days and other is Work.

Days

+--------+--------+
|day_id  | day     |
+-------+---------+
|   1   | Day 1   |
|   2   | Day 2   |
|   3   | Day 3   |
+-------+---------+

Work

+--------+--------+-----------+
|work_id |day_id | work      |
+--------+--------+-----------+
|    1   |   1   | ABC       |
|   2   |   2   | PQR       |
|   3   |   3   | XYZ       |
+-------+-------+-----------+

I want to have days in tab dynamically and i have populated it in a li using foreach.Now i want to display work for a particular tab
eg: Day 1 tab will have work ABC.So my question is how to select day_id and display work for that day and make tabs clickable.

My Controller

member:

```
    public function work_plan()
{
    $data['days'] = $this->member_model->get_days();
    $data['main_content'] = 'view';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

view:

```
     <ul class="tabs">

         <?php foreach($days as $curr_day): 
            $day_id = $curr_day['day_id'];
            $day    = $curr_day['day'];?> 

            <li><a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>member/work_plan"><?=$day;?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>

    <table>
      <tr>
          <td>No</td>
          <td>Work</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>ABC</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>PQR</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you using any theme @Snehal?

Comment: To achieve that result, you should use something like [jQuerUI tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) for example. Than you would need to pull out specific data with ajax and populate it in each tab.

Answer (score 0):

you will need something like that (this is just a hint)

but you will have to query the database to get the work_id and the day_id 
I am not a javascript expert but it should be similar to this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
        var currentId;
        var content;
          
        $(".subtabs").hover(function(){
            $(this).css("font-size","35px");
            $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
        },function(){
            $(this).css("font-size","24px");
        });

        $(".subtabs").click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('contentId') == currentId)
            {
                $(".subContents").animate({height:"0px"},1000);
                $(".subContents").html("");
            }
            else
            {
            $(".subtabs").css("background-color","");
            $(".subContents").animate({height:"0px"},1000);
            $(".subContents").html("");
            $(this).css("background-color","#0000BF");
            currentId = $(this).attr('contentId');
            content ="content here";
            $("div[id$="+currentId+"]").animate({height:"600px"},500);
            $("div[id$="+currentId+"]").html(content);
            }
        });

        $(".subtabs").toggle(function(){
        },
        function(){
            
        });
    });
```

```css
body
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #top
    {
        height: 20px;
    }
    .tabs
    {
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 850px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .subtabs
    {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        font-size: 24px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #4679BD;
    }
    .content
    {
    }
    .subContents
    {
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        height: 0px;
        width: 850px;
        background-color: #00ACEE;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    }
    .bottom
    {
        height: 3px;
        background-color: #00ACEE;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery 1.7.2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top"></div>
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="subtabs" contentId="uid1">work1</div>
    <div class="subtabs" contentId="uid2">work2</div>
    <div class="subtabs" contentId="uid3">work3</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="subContents" id="uid1"><p>content of work 1</p></div>
    <div class="subContents" id="uid2"><p>content of work 2</p></div>
    <div class="subContents" id="uid3"><p>content of work 3</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```